# Can one make causal inferences when outcome construct stability is low (i.e., standardized b = .1)?

Tags: inference, panel-data

I'm testing a longitudinal model with two time points (X1 predicting Y2 while controlling for Y1). The standardized stability coefficient (Y2 on Y1) is b = .1. It is safe to assume that much of the residual variance is due to measurement error and the rank order stability of Y is likely much higher, though unknown. This is common with this type of data (fMRI). My question is, if X1 significantly predicts Y2 while controlling for Y1 (it does at b ~ .1***), is this model any better than cross-sectional, given that Y1 explains so little of the variance in Y2? I am inclined to believe that controlling for outcome stability is not helpful here and this model is only marginally better (if at all) than cross-sectional for making causal claims. Thoughts? Experiences? Thanks.